# Objective-c protocol in swift issue

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I have a protocol in objective-c :

```
@protocol stuffDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) applyFiltersWithCuisines:(NSMutableArray *)cuisinesArray neighborhoods:(NSMutableArray *)neighborhoodsArray vibes:(NSMutableArray *) vibesArray;
@end
```

and i'm trying to use this method in swift :

```
func applyFiltersWithCuisines(cuisinesArray : NSMutableArray, neighborhoodsArray : NSMutableArray, vibesArray : NSMutableArray) -> () {
    println("do stuff")
}
```

having issues in swift file :

Type 'controller' does not conform the protocol 'stuffDelegate', any ideas ?

So problem is that it looks different in swift

Comment: Can you try marking `applyFiltersWithCuisines` as @optional?

Comment: problem is that if i'll make it @optional it doesn't call this delegate method anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter names are different in the protocol and the method. The protocol defines

```
-applyFiltersWithCuisines:neighborhoods:vibes:
```

The ObjectiveC signature of your Swift method (the @selector) would be

```
-applyFiltersWithCuisines:neighborhoodsArray:vibesArray:
```

They don't match.

Comment: exactly, one quick question, swift transforms NSArray (in obj-c) type to something else ?

Comment: I'm still figuring this out myself. I think an NSArray is equivalent to `[AnyObject]`. You can always use the NSArray type directly.